# What's the best way to answer when there's a really good answer elsewhere?

Tags: support, answering-advice

In researching the question [Which is correct, “buck naked” or “butt naked”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/22973/5822), I found a very thorough examination of this question at Language Log that I linked to in a comment under the OP. I feel like the information there deserves to be formatted as an answer to the question, but I'm not sure the best way to do that in a situation like this. I could:

- Keep it as a link in a comment (keeps good info kind of obscure).
- Cut & paste the whole Language Log post (excessive and possible [copyright](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/153/5822) issues).
- Just post a link to the discussion as an answer (possibly [rude](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-should-be-done-with-answers-that-contain-just-a-link/973#973), doesn't really incorporate good info into this site).
- Summarize and link (probably best, but seems redundant and awkward when the original post is concise, well written, well-researched and should really be read in its entirety).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Summarize and link**

Don't leave just a link. Linkrot will make the answer completely useless.

Don't copy-paste. There may be copyright issues and plagiarism is bad form.

If you offer a summary and a link, one can visit the link for more information. If the link ever disappears, the summary can provide the answer and, perhaps, the information to use to search for the text elsewhere.

Comment: I agree, plus if you past all of it, the OP won't understand anything, and you'll have to go around cutting, adjusting = too much work. It's easier and better to summarise and link.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion:

- Every answer should be understandable and accurate on its own should the (a) link stop working or (b) reader be lazy
- Answers should link to anything used as an authority when possible (exceptions being basic dictionary lookups)
- All quotes or paraphrases sourced with a link when possible
- In the event of pulling most of an answer from another excellent answer located elsewhere, try to hit some golden ratio between original content and heavy quoting. Walls of blockquotes are not attractive and feel cheeky.